# socket.io creates multiple sockets per connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Sometimes, when the server is under a bit of a load, when someone connects to the page, multiple sockets are created, if it is very laggy, the person may never connect while extra sockets are made repeatedly once every second, to infinity until it is stopped. Any idea to why it might do this?

Server side code:

```
var express = require('express'); //FOR LOCALHOSTING!
var Victor = require('victor');

var app = express();

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, listen);

function listen() {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log("server is up");
}

app.use(express.static('public'));

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Client-side:

```
var socket = io();
```

My intention is to only have one socket be made per web page connection, because a new player is generated for each socket created.

Note: If the server is given enough time, the server will actually remove the incorrectly created sockets (but not nearly fast enough to be practical)

Comment: Are you using socket.io-client ?

Comment: Yes of course...

Comment: How did you conclude that the server is opening a new socket for every connection ?

Comment: Every time a io.sockets.on("connection") is triggered it is console logged to the server... and I get that message multiple times along with seeing multiple players. As I said before, every socket connection makes a new player... and multiple players are being vreated

Comment: I think you'll have to show us the actual client and server socket.io code that you think is leading to this issue.  Right now, you only  show us your Express code which isn't really relevant.  And, I'd suggest you log both `connect` and `disconnect` messages on the server with the `socket.id` value and the current system time in the log message too so you can see the exact sequence of connects and disconnects and get some better idea of timing.  It's pretty hard for us to help without seeing the relevant code - there has to be more to it than what you show so far.

Comment: do you believe that this has nothing to do with the express code, but how I handle connections and generation of players?

Answer (score 0):

In this situation i would move to websocket logic in a [SharedWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker) or [ServiceWorker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers). It would reduce the number of connections to 1 for every user(browser).